# Automatic import XML to Oracle (tool, schedule task)

Tags: xml, oracle, import, task

I have a problem to solve. I will get XML-Files from different sources and need to import them into a oracle database. Currently I import them manually via a small Access-Tool.

But I want to automate the import process, now:

- Schedule an import task which imports the XML Files from a defined location into my oracle database
- Send Summary-Mail of imported data / fails
- Move imported XML-Files to an archive folder

Does someone know a tool providing these features?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Data Pump will give you the basic commands to do this, which you could then automate using the batch scheduler of your choice. More details on how you can import from a directory [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/xdb26imp.htm#ADXDB3000).

Comment: My hope was to handle this within a small tool. I also want to generate a summary email and I dont want to realize this all by my own. There must be a tool providing this somehwere?!

Comment: You can set the Data Pump to just query a directory and then import all the files it finds in there, and you just need to set a schedule to run that; cron on a Linux box or Task Scheduler on Windows would do the job. Then just dump the XML files and they'll magically appear in the DB the next time the job runs... doesn't get much simpler than that